# How to create a menu in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I'm looking to create a menu like the following: [Image of Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpgX9.jpg)

I've tried a context menu but not had the effect I wanted, I want the user to be able to click the 'Fixtures' Button and a menu come out the side like in the photo.

I have also tried having the button show different items of the menu but this didn't work either.

Anyone got any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: This sounds too broad, and asking for a tutorial is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you've tried so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: And tag your question with the UI framework you are using?  It looks like Windows Forms, but it's important to know

Comment: Are you trying to add a menu to the Visual Studio application itself, or are you using Visual Studio to create an application that you want to add a menu to? Because those are two very different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Windows Forms...

1. Create your button (myButton)
2. Create a "contextMenuStrip" on your form (from the Menus and Toolbars section of the tool box)
3. Add the commands you want to your Context menu strip control
4. In your button click handler do the following

Button click handler code:

```
 private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var corner = new Point(myButton.Right, myButton.Top);
     corner = PointToScreen(corner);
     contextMenuStrip1.Show(corner);
 }
```

This should work

Comment: @HarryBilney: You will have a **much** better chance of getting a good answer if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and learn how to create a [MCVE]